# There are no objects available and the waitQueue is full, scalikejdbc

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, akka, scalikejdbc

**Objective**
I want to update(replace) list of data in database.
Note -
When i run on list of size 10 there is no error. But when i run more than 10 i get below error. Sometime if run different repository similar code then i face same error.

**Error details -**

```
error = com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.PoolExhaustedException: There are no objects available and the waitQueue is full, errorCause = com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.PoolExhaustedException: There are no objects available and the waitQueue is full
```

**Code which i run -**

```
     db.withPool { implicit session =>
      EitherT.right[ApplicationError](repository.saveBulk(result)).value
    }
```

where -

```
  def withPool[A](f: SharedAsyncDBSession => Future[A]): Future[A]
```

Query -

```
override def saveBulk(myList: Seq[MyCaseClass])(
      implicit session: AsyncDBSession): Future[Unit] =
    if (myList.nonEmpty) {
      myList.map { m =>
        withSQL {
          insert
            .into(MyTable)
            .namedValues(autoNamedValues(m, column))
            .onConflictUpdateNamed(SQLSyntax.createUnsafely("id1, id2, datetime"))(
              autoNamedValues(m, column))
        }.execute.future().map(_ => ())
      }.head
    } else {
      Future.successful(())
    }
```